# Cannot find Audio Hardware for my Workstation

Tags: audio, alsa, scientific-linux

Audio is NOT working in HP workstation xw 4600.
I cannot find any hardware present at

> System-> Preferences -> Sound -> Hardware (Tab)

The command `lspci -v` shows following output of Audio Device:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0bee (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 5194
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

And when I am configuring via `alsamixer` and press tab  **F6**  [Select Sound Card], there is only one **default** option is present.

**Update 1:**  The output of the commands shows no hardware present ! is it True?

```
[root@target ~]# cat /proc/asound/cards   
--- no soundcards ---  
[root@target ~]# rmmod snd-hda-intel; modprobe snd-hda-intel  
ERROR: Module snd_hda_intel does not exist in /proc/modules
```

Is my hardware NOT properly installed OR I need proper drivers? If so, which?.

**Update 2:** After reconnecting the hardware and following *Gilles* instructions, the output is as below:

> [root@target ~]# modprobe snd-hda-intel
>   [root@target ~]# lsmod |grep '^snd_hda_intel'
>   snd_hda_intel          25771  0
>   [root@target ~]# uname -rv
>   2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010
>   [root@target ~]#

I **still** don't know which drivers should I install for proper functioning of this card, please help!

**Update 3:** Yes, I have tried configuring with alsaconf. But I get following errors:
`[root@target ~]# alsaconf`
[image]
[image]
[image]

and after this I got following Error Output.

> [root@target ~]# alsaconf
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-opl3sa2
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-cs4236
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-cs4232
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-cs4231
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-es18xx
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-es1688
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-sb16
>   ERROR: modinfo: could not find module snd-sb8
>   [root@target ~]#

Still NOT getting any hardware information:
[image]

Comment: So there is no card listed in `/proc/asound/cards`? Are there any error messages in the system log after you run `rmmod snd-hda-intel; modprobe snd-hda-intel`?

Comment: Thanks @CL please check the update. I think the hardware is not properly working!

Comment: If the hardware is suspect, it is probably far easier to plug in a known working card and boot that. Sure, this approach lacks elegance but it makes up for it in speed and lack of frustration.

Comment: That error message shows that the driver module was not loaded, and the absence of a second message shows that loading succeeded. Do you have a card now?

Comment: ok ... I will reattach the card...after sometime. As some services are running. Thanks

Comment: Your hardware is detected but you seem to be lacking the proper driver. After running `modprobe snd-hda-intel`, is the module loaded (check with `lsmod |grep '^snd_hda_intel'`)? What distribution are you running, what version, what kernel (output of `uname -rv`)?

Comment: Have you ran `alsaconf`?

Comment: 3rd Update:Please go through update... Again !!